# Autoencoder hits invisble wall

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, cross-validation, autoencoder

I have a problem. I am currently trying to train an autoencoder using Stock data. The data has been MinMax scaled.

The model seems to have an issue tranforming values lower than 0.15 and higher than 0.8. It looks like there is an invisible barrier. Not sure how to call this. How would you call it?

This is the models output vs original: Output vs Original

[image: 1]

My model uses the tanh activation function and consists of Linear Layers. The laten_dim is the same as the  input layer. I planned to reduce it later down the line:

```
class SparseEncoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_shape: int, latent_dims, dtype=torch.float64):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_shape, 512, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(512, 256, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(256, 128, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(128, 64, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear5 = nn.Linear(64, 32, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear6 = nn.Linear(32, 16, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear7 = nn.Linear(16, 8, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear8 = nn.Linear(8, latent_dims, dtype=dtype)

    def forward(self, x):
        # y = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear1(x))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear2(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear3(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear4(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear5(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear6(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear7(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear8(z))
        return z
```

```
class SparseDecoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_shape: int, latent_dims, dtype=torch.float64):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(latent_dims, 8, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(8, 16, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(16, 32, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(32, 64, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear5 = nn.Linear(64, 128, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear6 = nn.Linear(128, 256, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear7 = nn.Linear(256, 512, dtype=dtype)
        self.linear8 = nn.Linear(512, input_shape, dtype=dtype)

    def forward(self, x):
        # y = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear1(x))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear2(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear3(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear4(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear5(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear6(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear7(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.linear8(z))
        return z
```

Do you have any hints that could help me?

I tried to autoencode Stock market data and expected to see a 1:1 to the output since the latent space is still the same.

Comment: Could you add the decoder code please ?

Comment: @AlexandreCatalano Thank you for your reply. I added the decoder part. Its basically the same as the encoder, but in reverse.

Comment: By the way how would you call the issue? Is there a specific name for such behaviour?

Comment: I used the adam optimizer. If its relevant

Comment: I don't know how to call it sorry. I guess the problem is tanh itself, If your data are between [0:1] you only use half of the S shaped tanh. Maybe try a different activation function or change the shape of your input to be between [-1:1] sorry not to be more helpful

Comment: Thanks, I'll try maybe a Relu function. Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: If you find the solution please put it here, I am interested ^^

Comment: And yes Relu is a good candidate

Comment: Your code looks OK. Your question seems more relevant for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).